# What rule should be added to ESLint and Prettier to display nested functions correctly?

Tags: eslint, prettier

I have that function:

```js
export const getSomeDataAction =
  (value: string): AppThunk =>
    (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(getSomeData(value));
    };
```

Problem with indentation in lines 3-5. ESLint tells me that 4, 6 and 4 spaces should be added for lines 3-5. But when I save the changes, Prettier and ESLint automatically change the number of spaces for these lines and make them 2, 4 and 2 respectively

What types of rules might be in conflict in this example? and how to fix it?

**.prettierrc**

```json
{
  "printWidth": 80,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "endOfLine": "auto"
}
```

**.eslintrc**

```js
rules: {
  'react/jsx-indent': [2, 2],
  indent: [1, 2, { SwitchCase: 1 }],
}
```

**eslint**: 8.48.0

**prettier**: 3.0.2